# CRASH: Option C - Embed application and plugin frameworks in Xcode and Flutter framework with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, flutter, module, cocoapods, flutter-add-to-app

I have created a flutter module to integrate in native iOS.
Later created a pod file for that module.
Followed below link Option-C.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup

When I run the app on simulator it works fine but on device its get crash immediately  on launch.

Steps:

1. Added some flutter pod library in 'Framework, Libraries and Embedded Content'.
   Modified Embed as "Do Not Embed".
   Created a build (.ipa file).
   It install successfully  but gets crash immediately on launch.

[image]